# Why do I receive "WebSocket connection is closed: code = 1000 (OK), no reason"

Tags: python, websocket

I have the following server:

```
import os
import asyncio
import websockets


class Server:

    def get_port(self):
        return os.getenv('WS_PORT', '8765')

    def get_host(self):
        return os.getenv('WS_HOST', 'localhost')

    def start(self):
        return websockets.serve(self.handler, self.get_host(), self.get_port())

    async def handler(self, websocket, path):
        while True:
            async for message in websocket:
                await websocket.send(message)
```

and the client:

```
import asyncio
import websockets


async def msg():
    async with websockets.connect('ws://localhost:8765') as websocket:
        await websocket.send('test message')

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(msg())
```

When I execute `asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(msg())` I receive the following error:

```
websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosed: WebSocket connection is closed: code = 1000 (OK), no reason
```

Also `app.py` code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.6

import asyncio
from server import Server


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ws = Server()
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(ws.start())
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

P.S. Added `while True` to `handler` as suggested in the comment below. But I still receive that error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You aren't starting the server

`server.py`:

```
import os
import asyncio
import websockets


class Server:

    def get_port(self):
        return os.getenv('WS_PORT', '8765')

    def get_host(self):
        return os.getenv('WS_HOST', 'localhost')


    def start(self):
        return websockets.serve(self.handler, self.get_host(), self.get_port())

    async def handler(self, websocket, path):
      async for message in websocket:
        print('server received :', message)
        await websocket.send(message)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  ws = Server()
  asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(ws.start())
  asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

`client.py`

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3.6

import asyncio
import websockets

async def msg():
    async with websockets.connect('ws://localhost:8765') as websocket:

        await websocket.send('test message')
        msg = await websocket.recv()
        print(msg)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(msg())
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

Comment: Didn't help. I have created app.py that does that and still receive 1000... error

Comment: that's strange? This is working fine on python3.6. Can you add app.py code.

Comment: added. I also try it with python 3.6

Comment: [keeping connections open](http://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/cheatsheet.html#keeping-connections-open)
 try adding a  while loop in the handler function.  

    `while = True:
     async for message ..`

Comment: now `print()` works but `await websocket.send(message)` fails with 1000 error

Comment: in your client code add `msg = await websocket.recv()`
`print(msg)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162303/discussion-between-yohannes-libanos-and-shalakhin).