# How will the websockets work if there are more than 1 user trying to connect?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, websocket, python-asyncio

I know how to create a websocket server in Python , like discussed here:

[Why do I receive "WebSocket connection is closed: code = 1000 (OK), no reason"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48052806/why-do-i-receive-websocket-connection-is-closed-code-1000-ok-no-reason)

From my knowledge with TCP Sockets, I need to create a passive Socket and for each client an active Socket - will this be the same case with this code?

Example Server Code:

```
import os
import asyncio
import websockets


class Server:

    def get_port(self):
        return os.getenv('WS_PORT', '8765')

    def get_host(self):
        return os.getenv('WS_HOST', 'localhost')


    def start(self):
        return websockets.serve(self.handler, self.get_host(), self.get_port())

    async def handler(self, websocket, path):
      async for message in websocket:
        print('server received :', message)
        await websocket.send(message)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  ws = Server()
  asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(ws.start())
  asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

Example Client code:

```
import asyncio
import websockets

async def msg():
    async with websockets.connect('ws://localhost:8765') as websocket:

        await websocket.send('test message')
        msg = await websocket.recv()
        print(msg)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(msg())
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

The Client will be an app at the end, howeverI am not able to test it with several users at the same time, thus this question.

Comment: Your examples work as you would expect. I don't see an issue.

Comment: The question I have is, what happens if I have like 3000 users at the same time. Will they experience a delay the more people there are or is this handled with websockets (in comparison to TCP servers)

Comment: Each client will be handled by a separate coroutine, and those are lightweight, so you should be fine, provided that the coroutine handler doesn't do something very CPU-consuming. Regardless, the only way to be sure is to create 3000 connections and measure the response.

Comment: I will have several different app users at the end, will this lead to some issues, like one user is getting the answer from the other user since it is all on one socket?